# Calloc behaves differently on different computers

Tags: c, calloc

I have written the folowing code in C:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int func(int n, int * data){
  for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    data = realloc(data, i * sizeof(int));
    data[i - 1] = i;
  }
  return 0;
}

int main(void){

  int numb = 10;
  int * array = calloc(1, sizeof(int));
  func(numb, array);

  for(int j = 0; j < numb; j++){
    printf("%d \t", array[j]);
  }

  free(array);
  return 0;
}
```

On the first computer the output is as expected:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Now if I compile and run the same program on another computer, it outputs random integer values. What am I missing here? What do I do wrong? Why does the very same program have a different behaviour on different computers?

Comment: I guess on one of the computers, the `realloc` left the memory block in the same place and on the other computer it got moved.

Comment: The change you made to `data` inside the function does not affect `array` outside of the function, you need to make a `data` a pointer to a pointer to int (`int **data`).

Comment: Looks ok to me. What is the 'different computer'?

Comment: @IanAbbott got it right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior of this program is undefined. If it prints out what you expect on any computer, it's purely by coincidence.

```
  int * array = calloc(1, sizeof(int));
  func(numb, array);
```

You're passing `array` *by value* here, meaning whatever `func` does to it is invisible to the outer scope. Note that `realloc` is not guaranteed to return the same pointer, so you need to expect that `array` will be changed during the course of the call. Try passing a pointer to `array` instead.

```
int func(int n, int ** data){
  for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    *data = realloc(*data, i * sizeof(int));
    (*data)[i - 1] = i;
  }
  return 0;
}

...

    func(numb, &array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Following Ian Abbot comment, the minimal correction you can do is having `func()` return the newly allocated block:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int * func(int n, int * data)  // <-- Notice the * in the return value
{
  for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    data = realloc(data, i * sizeof(int));
    data[i - 1] = i;
  }
  return data; // <-- We return a pointer to the newly allocated memory block
}

int main(void)
{
  int numb = 10;
  int * array = calloc(1, sizeof(int));
  array = func(numb, array); // <-- reassign to array (same pattern as realloc)

  for(int j = 0; j < numb; j++){
    printf("%d \t", array[j]);
  }

  free(array);
  return 0;
}
```

In this way you are sure that if `realloc()` changed the position of the memory block it gets updated in array.

Answer (score 0):

Your program has undefined behaviour.  So, it is possible that it has different behaviours even in the same computer... Let me explain:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int func(int n, int * data){
  for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    // HERE, YOU CHANGE THE VALUE OF data FOR THE NEW
    // VALUE RETURNED BY REALLOC.  As the value ov array
    // was copied on entry, it is not known outside of
    // func()
    data = realloc(data, i * sizeof(int));
    data[i - 1] = i;
  }
  return 0;
  // AFTER THIS POINT THE ORIGINAL (the passed in value
  // to func() is not valid anymore
}

int main(void){

  int numb = 10;
  int * array = calloc(1, sizeof(int));
  func(numb, array);
  // at this point, the value of array is not valid,
  // in case the value realloc() has returned inside
  // func() has changed.

  for(int j = 0; j < numb; j++){
    printf("%d \t", array[j]);
  }

  // THIS IS ALSO INCORRECT.
  free(array);
  return 0;
}
```

A workaround to your problem is that you return the
new value back (the one returned by calloc()), as in

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *func(int n, int * data){
  for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    data = realloc(data, i * sizeof(int));
    data[i - 1] = i;
  }
  return data;
}

int main(void){

  int numb = 10;
  int * array = calloc(1, sizeof(int));
  // now array continues to be bvalid after the call to func().
  array = func(numb, array);

  for(int j = 0; j < numb; j++){
    printf("%d \t", array[j]);
  }

  free(array);
  return 0;
}
```

By the way, in order to be optimum, and as you know the final value that `i` will take in `func()` (`n`), you should write `func()` to make **only one call to `realloc()`** and this will be faster than reallocating once per value.

```
int *func(int n, int *data) {
  data = realloc(data, n * sizeof *data);
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    data[i-1] = i;
  return data;
}
```